# Factoring out a procedure

Tags: scheme

How could I use this procedure:

```
(define (sum f n ) 
  (if (= n 1)
      (f 1)
      (+ ( f n ) (sum f (- n 1)))))
```

in order to redefine the following one?

```
(define (zeno n)
  (cond ((= n 1)
         (/ 1 2))
        ((> n 1)
         (+ (zeno (- n 1))
            (/ 1 (expt 2 n))))))
```

Basically, I am trying to create another function called zeno-sec that uses the sum function written above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure `sum` accepts another procedure `f` and you have to find that `f`. If you look at the second procedure `zeno` you can spot a possible body of `f` in the second clause of `cond`, that is `(/ 1 (expt 2 n))`. So `f` will be `(lambda (a) (/ 1 (expt 2 a)))`. Combining it with `sum`, the `zeno-sec` will look like:

```
(define (zeno-sec n)
  (sum (lambda (a)
         (/ 1 (expt 2 a)))
       n))
```

Edit: Maybe some clarifications could help. If you look at the two procedures, `sum` and `zeno`, you can see they have very similar structure: a conditional form and a recursion. Also if you switch the places of the subexpressions in the last expressions you will notice that they are almost the same:

```
(+ (sum f (- n 1))
   (f n))
```

and

```
(+ (zeno (- n 1))
   (/ 1 (expt 2 n)))
```

See how the call `(zeno (- n 1))` resembles the `(sum f (- n 1))` and the `(f n)` becomes `(/ 1 (expt 2 n))`. I hope that makes some sense.